# How to fix a leaking concrete ceiling?

Tags: leak, ceiling

We are occupying the second floor of a 4 story apartment complex. We have recently moved in and all 4 floors are now occupied. The occupant in the first floor says his bedroom ceiling is leaking with water drops forming especially in the morning when the bathrooms are most used. There are two bathrooms near the leaking area (in our 2nd floor house). Unable to pinpoint the source, the constructor has started removing the floor tile of one of the bathrooms in our house. He expects to find moist cement underneath if it is the source. The problem is the source can also be from one of the two wash basin drains or from a poorly fixed PVC pipe tracking along the concrete structure. The building has a concrete wall design with no bricks. How do we identify the source of the leak accurately without having to open up the roof or the wall one after another? Is there any technology that can pinpoint the source of the water accurately?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming the place is built right or something close to normal & expected. You would drill a small hole (drinking straw or pencil sized) in the dripping area of the ceiling so an Endoscope Camera could be inserted to catch the leak in action. This would be repeated probably just 2 more times until the leaking pipe is found.

When drilling the hole you'd want a bucket underneath to catch any puddled water up there or just have towels on the floor around a bucket & insert a short bent piece of wire to direct the water down into the bucket.

Then, you rip out the entire ceiling & permanently fix the pipe & that means DO NOT use some screw-on piece of garbage that fake plumbers have been pushing for decades. The Landlord must be involved in all of this & must be the one to have the above performed by a Real Professional Plumber.